# How to get back to parent fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In parent fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_parent, container, false);

        //child fragment
        FragmentManager childFragMan = getChildFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction childFragTrans = childFragMan.beginTransaction();
        ChildFragment childFragment = new ChildFragment ();
        childFragTrans.add(R.id.FRAGMENT_CHILD, childFragment);
        childFragTrans.commit();
```

Then in child fragment i need to get back to Parent fragment (hide child fragment)
How to implement that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_parent, container, false);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        //child fragment
        FragmentManager childFragMan = getChildFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction childFragTrans = childFragMan.beginTransaction();
        ChildFragment childFragment = new ChildFragment ();
        childFragTrans.add(R.id.FRAGMENT_CHILD, childFragment, "childFragment");
        childFragTrans.commit();
    }
```

Then

```
FragmentManager childFragMan = getChildFragmentManager();
Fragment childFragment = childFragMan.findFragmentByTag("childFragment");
FragmentTransaction childFragTrans = childFragMan.beginTransaction();
childFragTrans.remove(childFragment);
childFragTrans.commit();
```

Comment: But how I remove childFragment in childFragment ?

Comment: null object reference on childFragTrans.remove(childFragment);

Comment: Do you also using activities? I guess it is easier to handle with activities instead of fragments

Comment: i using with fragments, i just need switch between 2 fragments

Comment: It's only NPE if you are not using the correct tag to find the fragment. Also if you can nest Activities like this, then that's great but that API was deprecated in API 11.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce actualy you answer was right, thank for help